# Is it possible to handle the Storyboard.Completed Event in such a way that a command from the ViewModel is called in Xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, events, binding, command

I solved the problem in such a way that there is an `EventHandler` in the Code-Behind which then calls the corresponding `Command` of the `ViewModel`.

```xml
<Storyboard x:Key="StartNewGameAnimation" RepeatBehavior="1x"
            Completed="StartAnimationCompleted">
```

```cs
private void StartAnimationCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var gameBoardViewModel = (GameBoardViewModel)this.DataContext;
    gameBoardViewModel.StartGameWhenStartanimationCompletedCommand.Execute(null);
}
```

This solution works fine, but I want to handle the `Event` directly in *Xaml* and also call the `Command`. It is simply important to me whether this path exists.

Comment: Maybe you could use an [EventToCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/may/mvvm-commands-relaycommands-and-eventtocommand#commands-for-every-element) implementation.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in what you are doing. You can improve your code in order to decouple it from the actual view model by adding a StartGameCommand property of type ICommand to the control (consider to let it implement ICommandSource). Then invoke this command in code-behind - the view model/DataContext is unknown at this point. Then in XAML bind the view model command to the control's StartGameCommand property. This way the control does not have to know the view model (type cast is removed). It can now operate with any type i.e. DataContext independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the *[Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf)* NuGet package that replaces the legacy [Interactivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/design-tools/expression-studio-4/ff725917(v=expression.40)) types. There is an `InvokeCommandAction` type that can invoke a command through an `EventTrigger`.

However, the direct way inside `Storyboard` does not work.

```
<Storyboard x:Key="StartNewGameAnimation" RepeatBehavior="1x">
   <b:Interaction.Triggers>
      <b:EventTrigger EventName="Completed">
         <b:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding StartGameWhenStartanimationCompletedCommand}"/>
      </b:EventTrigger>
   </b:Interaction.Triggers>
</Storyboard>
```

It will throw an exception at runtime, because the `Storyboard` cannot be frozen with the binding.

> 'Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Interactivity.EventTrigger' must have IsFrozen set to false to modify

A workaround is to move the interaction block to a parent element, e.g. `BeginStoryboard` and refer to the `Storyboard` with an `ElementName` binding.

```
<BeginStoryboard>
   <b:Interaction.Triggers>
      <b:EventTrigger EventName="Completed" SourceObject="{Binding ElementName=StartNewGameAnimation}">
         <b:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding StartGameWhenStartanimationCompletedCommand}"/>
      </b:EventTrigger>
   </b:Interaction.Triggers>
   <!-- ...other code. -->
   </Storyboard>
</BeginStoryboard>
```

Depending on the context, setting the `SourceName` instead of `SourceObject` works, too.

```
<b:EventTrigger EventName="Completed" SourceName="StartNewGameAnimation">
```

By the way, you have to add the following XML namespace in your control, to refer to the types:

```
xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.